# How to make a specific Item with specific tags do something special

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I should have explained in more detail, so I have six altars and when you make them, and drop items on them, it transforms your items. It adds special tags so I can detect if they have been enchanted by that altar, and it adds two tags, (one of the colors) Altar and reforged.I just finished everything having to do with the lowest tier of altar, the purple altar. I decided to work on the bow first because it was easier than the others. I added the fireworksSpark to all arrows and now I just need to put a `/testfor` so I can detect a bow with purpleAltar and reforged. Easy enough. I'm doing this:

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{minecraft:bow:{tag:{Tags:["purpleAltar","reforged"]}}}}
```

. It always says data does not match for MutantCookie07 when I'm holding it. I'm in 1.10 by the way.

Comment: Do you have any pictures we could see?

Comment: I do, but I'm on an iPad, and my command creation is on computer

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the difference in selectors as you used `@a` which will only search for all **Players** and not entities, try using `@e` which tests for all **entities**. At the moment the only entity you are testing is yourself and the tags don't match so that is the cause of the error message.

Comment: I edited my question so read that and try something else

Comment: The issue is still the selector at the start try changing that first @Command_block